# CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation causing view rotation on iOS6

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, ios6, cgaffinetransform

I have create an empty project that only allows landscape orientations with a storyboard containing only a UIViewController as rootViewController with a button in its center.

[image: landscape orientation only]

[image]

```
- (IBAction)onClick:(UIButton *)sender {
    sender.superview.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-320, 0);
}
```

The expected is that when clicking that button the view moved 320 to the left, but unfortunately what happens is that the view is rotating anti-clockwise and moving left at the same time. It seems that somehow the application thinks it is set to the portrait view and it translate the view taking that into account and this is what happens:

[image: rotating instead moving left]

I'm sure I am missing something here but I have no idea what it is.

I've tried to defined methods on the viewController such `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate` and `- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations` but it didn't change this behaviour.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your app has a `UIWindow`, which contains your root view controller's view, which contains the button:

- `UIWindow`

  - your root view

    - `UIButton`

What you didn't understand is that the `UIWindow` rotates the user interface by applying a rotation transform to your root.  Take a look at the view hierarchy when the interface is in landscape-left orientation:

```
(lldb) po [[UIApp keyWindow] recursiveDescription]
(id) $1 = 0x0922ee80 <UIWindow: 0x942c280; frame = (0 0; 768 1024); layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x942c380>>
   | <UIView: 0x9432b30; frame = (20 0; 748 1024); transform = [0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0]; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x9432be0>>
   |    | <UIRoundedRectButton: 0x942f7a0; frame = (476 352; 73 44); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x942f8c0>>
   |    |    | <UIGroupTableViewCellBackground: 0x94300b0; frame = (0 0; 73 44); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x9430180>>
   |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x9430af0; frame = (1 1; 71 43); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x9431340>>
   |    |    | <UIButtonLabel: 0x94319c0; frame = (12 12; 49 19); text = 'Button'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x9431d10>>
```

See how the `UIWindow`'s subview (`UIView: 0x942c380`) has a transform of `[0, -1, 1, 0, 0, 0]`?  That transform rotates your top-level view 90˚ counter-clockwise.  If you rotate your device (or the simulator) to landscape-right orientation, you will see that the transform becomes `[0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0]`:

```
(lldb) po [[UIApp keyWindow] recursiveDescription]
(id) $2 = 0x07436d90 <UIWindow: 0x942c280; frame = (0 0; 768 1024); layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x942c380>>
   | <UIView: 0x9432b30; frame = (0 0; 748 1024); transform = [0, 1, -1, 0, 0, 0]; autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x9432be0>>
   |    | <UIRoundedRectButton: 0x942f7a0; frame = (476 352; 73 44); opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x942f8c0>>
   |    |    | <UIGroupTableViewCellBackground: 0x94300b0; frame = (0 0; 73 44); userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x9430180>>
   |    |    | <UIImageView: 0x9430af0; frame = (1 1; 71 43); opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x9431340>>
   |    |    | <UIButtonLabel: 0x94319c0; frame = (12 12; 49 19); text = 'Button'; clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; userInteractionEnabled = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x9431d10>>
```

When you reset the view's transform, you're losing the rotation, so the view reverts to its “default” rotation of 0˚, which is the portrait rotation.

Adam Lockhart's answer will fix this temporarily, but if the user rotates the device, the `UIWindow` will reset your view's transform, losing the translation you applied.

The correct way to handle this is to *not* apply your own transform to your top-level view.  Give your top-level view a subview that you can transform, and put your button inside that:

- `UIWindow`

  - your root view

    - your transformable view

      - `UIButton`

Comment: This is incorrect. A transformation applied to the window will not undo any transformations of views and subviews therein.  It would merely apply the transform to the window.

Comment: @AdamLockhart I didn't talk about applying transforms to the window, and zanona's code doesn't apply a transform to the window either.  I talked about applying transforms to the subview of the window, which is what zanona's code does.  I tested my solution and I tested yours.  Yours loses the translation if the interface is rotated to another orientation.

Comment: You wrote "the UIWindow will reset your view's transform, losing the translation you applied".  This is implausible. I have tested this too. I have software in which the positioning of EVERYTHING relies on applying transformations.  If these transformations were lost when the user rotated the device, it would be absurd.

Comment: @AdamLockhart You left out “if the user rotates the device” when you quoted me.  I have added another view hierarchy printout to my answer.  Look at the transform on `UIView: 0x942c380`.  See how it changes from the first printout (landscape-left orientation) to the second printout (landscape-right orientation)?  The system changed the transform because I rotated the simulator 180˚.

Comment: @AdamLockhart Note that the system only changes the window's root view's transform on rotation.  (That is, it changes `window.rootViewController.view.transform`.)  It doesn't change the transforms of any subviews of the root view, and it doesn't change the transforms of any other views you manually add to the window, and it doesn't change the transform of the window itself.

Comment: Right. So, all you are saying is that he shouldn't apply the transform to the outermost view.  Agreed!  That would be absurd.

Comment: Although here you are only making an assumption about what might be a root view controller's view.  It would make more sense to assume that it is not, which could be why I misread this long post.

Comment: Honestly, I only recently got hooked on this site because of a work question. I would have read your response more carefully if I wasn't looking at this at work today. I need to go back to my super-genius level sudoku crack, because this gamification-based nerd-spliotation site is seriously addictive. You might consider if you, yourself have a problem with it...

Comment: @AdamLockhart Yeah, I thought I'd stop when I [unlocked all the privileges at 20k…](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges)

Comment: Thanks both Rob and Adam, the explanation was really thorough and easy to understand I could reflect that on css transform while coming from web design background. I will certainly make sure I only perform transformations on subviews now. I have to say that now I am having problems with iOS6 auto-layout which won't let me move objects, but I will leave that to another question ;)

Answer (score 2):

You need to apply the transform to its existing transform.

```
- (IBAction)onClick:(UIButton *)sender {
    sender.superview.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(sender.superview.transform, -320, 0);
}
```